# Error displaying details (ObjectContext instance has been disposed)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 3 app and I've got a model that looks something like so:

```
public partial class Flavor
{
   // ...
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool HasNuts {get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<SaleData> Sales {get; set;}
   // ...
}
```

which retrieves some data from a db as such:

```
public PartialViewResult Details(int id)
{
   using (var db = new IceCreamDBFlavors())
   {
      Flavor someFlavor = db.Flavors.Find(id);
      someFlavor.Sales = db.Sales.Where(c => c.FlavorID == id).ToList();
      return PartialView("details", someFlavor);      
   }
}
```

over on the view I do something like this:

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Sales Data</legend>
   @foreach (var sale in Model.Sales)
   {
      <div>Weekly</div>
      <div>@sale.Weekly</div>
   }
</fieldset>
```

If I don't retrieve the Sales data, my Flavor data displays fine with no errors, but adding the call to retrieve the list of sales data causes an error **"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."** to occur.

I've read a few other posts about this and guess I'm missing something here.  I believe this error happens due to lazy loading, at least based on what I've read here and elsewhere.  Setting a breakpoint in the Controller before returning the PartialView and checking the object, I believe, causes the evaluation to take place, so everything displays as I would want.

I was under the impression that the `ToList()` call would force the Sales collection to be filled in.  Since I don't have the issue when that line's commented out, I assume the problem is still related to that and when the View is attempting to iterate the Sales, it can't.  Am I correct here?  I guess I *thought* I was forcing the evaluation.  How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't dispose the IceCreamDBFlavors class that inherits from ObjectContext, it needs to have a lifetime greater than is currently allowed.

Change

```
using (var db = new IceCreamDBFlavors())
{
  Flavor someFlavor = db.Flavors.Find(id);
  someFlavor.Sales = db.Sales.Where(c => c.FlavorID == id).ToList();
  return PartialView("details", someFlavor);      
}
```

To

```
try
{
    var db = new IceCreamDBFlavors();

    Flavor someFlavor = db.Flavors.Find(id);
    someFlavor.Sales = db.Sales.Where(c => c.FlavorID == id).ToList();
    return PartialView("details", someFlavor);    
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // log exeption
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed the issue.  I guess I need to re-examine *why* IceCreamDBFlavors needs a greater lifetime.

Comment: @itsmatt No problem, this one caught me out too. It needs a greater lifetime because the existing using statement disposed of the object context, then slightly later in the same request (in the view) the lazy loading needs to use the object context again to drill down further into the data. You could use some logic that disposes of the object context at the end of the request.

Comment: No, no no, this is bad and the type of code that should never make it into a production system!  Your basically saying running SQL in the View is OK and opening up all the possibility for SELECT N+1 issues.

Comment: @jfar - Appreciate the comment.  How would do this differently?

Comment: @itsmatt - You'r questions code is fine except you have lazy loading going on someplace like Aliostad pointed out.  The easiest way to prevent this problem from ever happening is to use view models.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion is that `Flavor` has other collections (and not just `Sales`) and it is in fact at the time of accessing those that it breaks.

Here you are replacing only Sales while other collections or complex properties would still need the object context.